# How to connect cPanel in a website using Python?

Tags: python, database, cpanel

I have the web address of a cPanel, for example : http://www.banada.com/cpanel and the username and the passord. I also have the info of the database and table name. I need to make a SELECT query from that table. How can I do that using Python ? 
Besides, do I need to provide info of my IP address to get started ?

The table in the web-page is as following: 
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do the query trough cPanel? Instead use db connection.

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

Comment: I indeed need to insert some data in the table, I was asking as if I can connect and make the query, then I will be able to insert the data as well.The tutorial doesn't tell how to connect with external cPanel.

Comment: But why trough cPanel?

Comment: I'm working for someone and they gave me the cPanel address of their webpage. I have the info mentioned in the question. 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )
How to change the "localhost" to the cPanel address ?

Comment: You dont need to change that, becouse the code will run on the same server where the db will. (localhost)

Comment: This doesn't work, I mean I'm running the script in my computer and the database is somewhere else.

Comment: You must read manual of Cpanel. Access to MySQL area of CPanel. And you need user and password with permission for use this database. Certains sys admins, block use of cpanel user owned mysql databases.